# XQuery: How to get system path separator?

Tags: path, operating-system, xquery

I would like to know if there is a possibility to get the system path separator inside my XQuery code without special libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's nothing defined in the [XQuery 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) or [XQuery 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/) specs to identify details of the filesystem.

However, using [`fn:doc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc), you should be able to reference filesystem URIs generally by preceding the file name with `file:///` and using `/` as a separator for directory.

Comment: Hi wst, thanks for your answer. I don't want to read files directly with `fn:doc()`. I just build the filename+complete path in XQuery and provide it to another processor which is not based on XQuery. To be precisely, I have a XML message with some information, I execute XQuery based on these information, build the filename and send it to another process.

Comment: @christian.vogel If possible, consider using a language that's more suitable for executing this task, like Java.

Comment: in the end I have choose Java. In my context I could first execute XQuery and in the process chain I could easily add the Java step to produce the correct file path. Thanks. I upvoted since everything you have said was to my expectations ;)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, I don't think it is possible to achieve this by using standard XQuery functionality. However, depending on what processor you are using, it is quite likely that you can use Java bindings. I am aware that at least [BaseX](http://basex.org), [eXist](http://exist-db.org) and [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) support this.

By using this technique you can get the separator

```
declare namespace system="java:java.lang.System";
system:getProperty("file.separator")
```

Or if your processor supports the expanded QName notation you can also write

```
Q{java:java.lang.System}getProperty("file.separator")
```